# Neglect terms of order $1/n$

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I have expressions like the following $A+B/n+C/n^2+\cdots,Z/n^p$. I'd like to keep just the first two terms, i.e., $A+B/n,$ however it seems that using the command
    O[1/n^2]
is not working. The
    O[]
command used to neglect higher-order terms seems to work only for expressions like $$A+B n+C n^2+\cdots,Z n^p.$$ Is there any workaround to deal with expressions like mine?

Answer (score 5):

Given:

```
expr = a + b/n + c/n^2 + d/n^3;
```

Use either:

```
expr + O[n, Infinity]^2 //TeXForm
```

> $a+\frac{b}{n}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right)$

or:

```
Series[expr, {n, Infinity, 1}] //TeXForm
```

> $a+\frac{b}{n}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right)$